# Custom redirect URI not working for Keycloak's client

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

I am seeking guidance regarding an issue with Keycloak. Specifically, I have set up a realm named as **Demo** and using **account-console** client for user authentication and login redirection. I have also implemented a custom SPI to handle the redirection and authentication process. However, when I attempt to use a custom redirect URI instead of the default one for the account-console client, it does not work.

Could anyone provide insights on how to resolve this issue? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**Default Setting for redirect URI in below screenshot** in this case every thing works fine
[image]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
but when I put my custom redirect URI it show error setting and error screenshot attached below.[image]

[image]

The client's default settings are functioning properly. However, my attempts to use a custom redirect URI, specifically http://localhost:8090/*, have failed. I have attempted to create a new client with the same custom redirect URI, but the outcome remains unchanged.

---

I have also tried creating a new client as per recommended by `@Arnold Obdeijn` .

below are the setting in new client setting

[image]

**

- let me explain some more what I am trying to do :

**

When user will click the below

- sign in
  button user will be redirected e.g. [www.iam.com](http://www.iam.com) on this website user will login with its credentials. Then [www.iam.com](http://www.iam.com) will return response with **signed JWT** containing info, which is being handled with custom SPI.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do here? If you want to use Keycloak as an identity provider for an application, don't use the built in account-console client but create a new client, like described here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#proc-creating-oidc-client_server_administration_guide

Any special reason why you have implemented a custom SPI to handle the redirection and authentication process?

If you get the error "invalid parameter: redirect_uri" check the value of the query parameter redirect_uri and see if it matches what you have added as valid redirect uri's for the client.

Comment: I have created custom SPI for redirection login service, the login service returns the **signed JWT** containing the user info, I am saving that info as **attributes** in the keycloak users. `@Arnold Obdeijn` am new with keycloak

Comment: I have updated the question also for better understanding, please check and guide @arnold-obdeijn